# Why are there so few volunteers in the Hunger Games?

Tags: the-hunger-games

As the first book describes it, volunteering in districts other than 1-2 and 4 is highly unusual and usually done only to save a relative which got chosen. 
I wonder why that is. There are especially two districts whose tributes stand a good chance:

1. District 7 in the Hunger Games Wiki is described as "District 7 provides lumber for the Capitol, and its people are known to be good with axes."
2. District 11 has a big population, most of which work in agriculture. Those are people who have a pretty rough life and who will not be lost in the wilderness (like the district 12 miners or the factory workers from district 8.)
   True, they are not trained in combat like the 'career' tributes, but it seems they still have a good chance to win. Thresh got close to the finish and even twelve year old Rue got pretty far in the 74th games.

So why is no one desperate enough to volunteer to escape the clutches of poverty?

Comment: Being able to chop down a tree with an axe does not equate to being battle capable with one. Trees don't move.

Comment: "the clutches of poverty" - you've got the makings of an answer there. Poverty tends to make people malnourished, and malnourished people don't fight well.

Comment: @Randal'Thor if you want your slave to chop down trees you got to feed him. Those guys may not eat gourmet food but they are in pretty good physical form and used to hard conditions.

Comment: @Neeshka Slaves IRL were often underfed anyway. You can beat your slave until he chops down trees, even if he's not really physically up to the task. It might be more rational/efficient to feed them well, but since when have totalitarian governments been rational?

Comment: +paulie_d missed a chance to paraphrase Bruce Lee:  "Trees do not hit back!"

Comment: i don't get why you would assume volunteers would expect to win.  i'm surprised the terminally ill don't volunteer for perfect strangers every single time a healthy young person is picked. surely every district has at least one kid with leukemia too poor to get treatment.

Comment: Where, exactly, did you make the jump from "good with cutting down trees" to "likely to survive a 24-person high-tech brawl to the death"?

Comment: @TylerH You really cant see the advantages of growing up in a forest region and being good at handling axes and other worktools?
There was even a line in Catching Fire about Joanna being dangerous cos she grew up throwing axes. D7 kids could go partisan, hide in the forest and take out the careers one by one. They wouldn't even know what hit them.

Comment: I completely agree with @Neeshka here. In fact there are myriad things that you do not learn about the wild when growing up in the city that could save your life. I heard something on BBC Radio 4 this morning about some city kids going camping and thinking it rained over night because the ground and tent were covered in dew; they'd never seen it before having grown up in a city. This could well save your life if dehydrated.

Comment: @Neeshka There are advantages, yes, but you are also making some *big* assumptions. When the map is an urban sprawl instead of a forest area, the kids from the woods are going to be up a creek without a paddle. Now it's the kids who know about wiring traps and traversing hi-rises who have an advantage. And a water arena? Now it's the fishers and swimmers who are dominating with their domain knowledge.

Comment: Besides, training tributes for combat like they do in 1, 2, and 4 is not blind "military training". It is training for them to compete in and win the Hunger Games, specifically. They get training on wilderness survival, camping, fishing, cooking, camouflage, etc. because they've had roughly 75 years to learn what kind of time the tributes have to expect when the Games start. You have to be able to survive in the woods, on an island, in a city, in a desert, underground, etc.

Comment: @TylerH "Often there are trees, because barren landscapes are dull and the Games resolve too quickly without them." Also: Katniss' tactics was to destroy the careers' food supplies arguing they aren't capable finding food in the wilderness.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

### Poverty doesn't make for good fighters.

The people in the outlying districts live on the brink of starvation. They're deliberately oppressed, kept poor and ignorant and most importantly *weak*. Poverty implies malnutrition, and malnourished people don't tend to fight well. For the same reason, armies (especially in poor countries) tend to be more well-fed and in better health than the majority of the population. But what army is there in Panem? The Peacekeepers come from the Capitol or - like Career Tributes - from District 2. From the authorities' point of view, there's no need to ensure *any* of the people in the outlying districts are in good health or properly fed, especially as children when they're not so useful as labour power.

Sure, some of the tributes from District 7 might be able to use axes, or those from District 11 might be good at living rough, but that usually doesn't make up for the **years of combat training** that the battle-hardened Career Tributes from Districts 1, 2, and 4 have been through. Career Tributes, brought up in relative luxury, have been able to afford the time to be trained, while those from poorer districts haven't.

Add to this the fact that **the tributes are only children**. Sure, District 7 has big strong men who can handle axes, but a boy or girl of fifteen won't be as strong and certainly not as efficient in personal combat. This, though, is something that puts District 12 at more of a disadvantage than the others: as Katniss notes in *Catching Fire*, kids in District 7 are put to work on the trees at an earlier age than those in District 12 are allowed to work in the mines. Which brings us to ...

### Maybe there *are* more volunteers in other districts.

Canonically we know that volunteering is almost unknown in District 12:

> District 12 
>   hasn't had a volunteer in decades and the protocol 
>   has become rusty. The rule is that once a tribute's 
>   name has been pulled from the ball, another eligible 
>   boy, if a boy's name has been read, or girl, if a girl's 
>   name has been read, can step forward to take his or 
>   her place. In some districts, in which winning the 
>   reaping is such a great honor, people are eager to risk 
>   their lives, the volunteering is complicated. But in 
>   District 12, where the wordtribute is pretty much 
>   synonymous with the word corpse, volunteers are all 
>   but extinct.
>
> <sub>-- *The Hunger Games*, Chapter 2</sub>

But it sounds as though there could well be occasional volunteers from other districts, not just the Careers:

> One by one, we see the other reapings, the names 
>   called, the volunteers stepping forward or, more 
>   often, not.
>
> <sub>-- *The Hunger Games*, Chapter 3</sub>

You're assuming that volunteering is almost unheard of in *all* districts outside of 1, 2, and 4, but I don't think the text of the book actually says that. It could be that it's *most* common in the districts of the Career Tributes, less common but still occasional in other districts, and rarest of all in District 12.

Comment: True, we dont for sure if there are usually volunteers in 7 & 11  i assumed it's not done seeing no one took Tresh and Rue's place in the 74th games. And both tributes of district 7 died in the first bloodbath.

Comment: @Neeshka For all we know, Thresh might have volunteered. He was certainly big and strong enough to have a damn good chance of winning.

Comment: it probably would have been mentioned if Thresh was a volunteer,  but could be... who knows.

Comment: That quote from the Hunger Games (Chapter 2) pretty much answers the question. Volunteer = 1:24 Chance you Don't Die. I have to mention that in many games the elements/environment, thirst and hunger sometimes kill more tributes than actual fighting....

Comment: @LeHill I think your quote does quite the opposite. It shows why those from 7 and 11 would stand a really good chance in the games.

Comment: @josh I am confused about this argument. Say the chance of a great tribute is 1:3 rather than 1:24. Would you want to take a 2 in 3 chance you die gruesomely in the next days? Would you put your kids into an academy that trains them for this? I think it is more confusing why there are careers in some districts than that there are no careers in most.

Comment: @xLeitix - Would you put your kids into a lifetime of training and preparation for an endeavor that has a not great chance of fame and fortune, and either way, has a great chance to leave them hopelessly brain-damaged?  In our society, we see that with parents who want their kids to be the next great NFL football (American) star. Do parents tend more towards objective analysis when it comes to their own kids, or wildly unrealistic and optimistic views of their kids' characteristics. Then multiply that by the arrogance of training the kid with the best experts money can buy. Food for thought.

Comment: @xLeitix I certainly get your point. I for one would not, but then having grown up in socially secure England I wouldn't take this risk. Someone who had grown up in poverty might well feel it is a gamble worth taking!

Comment: @AndrewMattson I would guess that the number of aspiring NFL stars would go down a bit if only 1 out of 24 players would leave the playing field alive, and the rest gets gruesomely slaughtered. Yes, parents do stupid things, but we are talking about a different, and, importantly, much more obvious, level of stupid here.

Comment: @xLeitix - That's why it's a dystopian vision of the future.  You'll notice that  the well-off people in the capitol district are pretty twisted and not well-adjusted, so this doesn't conflict with that all that much.  :D

Comment: @Neeshka - yes, but we're talking more about why the well-off families would send their kids to expensive training, so they can eventually volunteer in the more well-off districts, which can be a bit more perplexing.

Comment: @AndrewMattson maybe those are orphans or indeed the society is messed up. After all they like to watch really hardcore stuff like Cato being tortured for hours. There are cultures nowadays too where the families are very proud of their child who sacrifices himself/herself and encourage stuff like that. ..and those are not necessary poverty stricken families

Comment: @Neeshka - they're pretty specific that these are sometimes children of privilege in those districts who train so they can win the glory.  So, yeah, more "society is messed up," is what we're supposed to take from it, I guess.  :D

Comment: @josh I am specifically referring to this part in that quote: "... where the word tribute is pretty much synonymous with the word corpse". To me, this means these people understand that if you volunteer, you die.

Comment: @LeHill What surprises me more, I guess, is that those from D1 and D2 would risk their super comfortable lives in a 1:24 bet. Even if it is a 1:4 (as there are the other three from D1 and D2) it seems like madness. If you have seemingly nothing to lose and maybe even welcome death a 1:4 feels worth considering. Then you can factor in that your entire life is essentially survival training and if you die you do so basking in gory glory... hell, "I volunteer".

Comment: I feel like real life offers little support for this. Violence tends to be more respected in the poorest neighborhoods than in the richest ones, and many kids who cannot afford good education see sports (i.e. physically demanding activities that require a lot of training) as a way out. Whether or not they are likely to be *better* at it than richer kids is a separate question from whether or not they are more likely to volunteer.

Answer (score 9):

The tributes from districts 1 and 2 almost always win because they train all their lives (even though that's against the rules).  Almost every year they see someone from district 1 or 2 win.  It's obviously all but a death sentence, and given the relative poverty in the outlying districts it seems like nobody there will have the time to train since birth.

Comment: Yes, but isnt it because the 'best' of them volunteer and cooperate? Training is important, i agree, but isn't manual labour and handling tools also is a kind of training? say two people from district 11 team up and volunteer. A guy like Thresh and a girl who is as old as him and as tough and also innovative. They can agree that whoever survives will help the other's family. Wouldn't they stand a chance?

Comment: @Neeshka manual labor and handling tools will make you stronger and *very slightly* better at fighting with those tools, but it's still nothing compared to *real* training. Plus, most tools aren't very similar to weapons, and even if they are you still don't know how to use it as a weapon.

Comment: @Neeshka I answered the question about teaming up [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108929/why-didnt-the-weaker-tributes-gang-up-on-the-stronger-ones-in-the-hunger-games?rq=1).

Comment: @Neeshka - No. Manual labor and handling tools is not any kind of training in lethal martial combat skills.  At all. I've trained in a system that has over 30 techniques for breaking joints when someone grabs the wrist, specifically, all differing techniques depend on how the wrist is grabbed. Picking up and throwing sacks of flour might give some very general possible advantages, vs nothing, but compared to actual combat skills training, almost no chance of coming out ahead.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because people have the belief that starvation is a lesser evil then the cruelties of the games,
Just because your starving to death and need food doesn't necessarily mean you want to be killed another way like tracker jackers turning you insane or mist that burns you slowly to death or mutts that slowly eat you alive or drowning or the countless other ways you can die in the games, maybe most people have the belief that they'd rather just starve then be killed what they believe to be a more traumatic way.

Comment: What you say seems plausible, but this seems a speculative answer. Do you have any quotes to back this up?

Answer (score 0):

### They Don’t Want to Die

Would you want to volunteer when your odds are 1/24? Especially if you were from one of the poorer districts like 12 or 8, where you don’t have any way to survive unless you are very smart or good with a weapon. Your odds would be more like 1/48, including your not having any survival skills and the careers having packs and multiple weapons.

Answer (score -1):

With the exception of Districts 1, 2, and 4, the other districts (especially the higher numbered ones, such as 8, 10, 11, and 12) live in abject, dire poverty. Poverty and undernourishment makes a person weak, and therefore in poor shape to fight, and therefore be able to win the games. By contrast, tributes from wealthier Districts (the Career Districts) are better fed, and have opportunities to train for the games from a young age. This is why they almost always place highly in the Hunger Games.

Comment: sorry but you are not adding additional information to other answers, you may want to check that before answering.